# How to save video capture in progress if user taps home button to terminate app

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to capture video.
I have set the delegate to save the captured video when video capture is stopped.
The delegate does get called when stopVideoCapture is called by the program based on user action.

I would like the same actions to also happen if while video capture is in progress the user presses the home button to terminate the app.

I tried adding call stopVideoCapture in applicationWillTerminate but for some reason the delegate action to save the video is not being called.  The imagePickerController delegate is a separate view controller and not the UIApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 4.0, `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called when the user presses the home button. Instead, see `applicationDidEnterBackground:` (or have your view controller listen to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification). Try setting up a background task with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.

Comment: Ole, my app is not supporting background mode so applicationWillTerminate does get called (I verified with breakpoint).

Answer (score 0):

You should check iOS 4.0 support for **short-time background tasks before exit**, check beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.

Here's link to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).